# Quantifying performance of machine learning methods

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, random-forest

I am new to machine learning and I just finished implementing my first method (`Random Forests`). Now I want to analyze how accurate this method actually is. The first performance metric that I used was to calculate how many correct predictions were made using the following formula:

`accuracy = correct predictions / total predictions * 100`

Now, I want to predict a variable with values of either `1` or `0`. Most of my predictions fall in a range between `1` and `0` `(0.85, 0.45, 0.95 etc..)`, hence these were not considered to be a correct prediction - resulting in an accuracy of `0.42%` using the above formula. I know that I am doing something very stupid and wrong. Shall I round the predicted values to the nearest integer, and then calculate the metrics?

Also, I ran an `AUC` test and it resulted in an accuracy of `81%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to verify the accuracy of your model would be to run a validation set approach (as you seem to be doing) or a Cross-Validation (K-Folds), more on that here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_test,_and_validation_sets

As for the variables, this seems to be a classification problem (your output variable can either be 0 or 1).

Thus a good approach would be to use classifiers that return you either 0 or 1 (and not something in the middle). Random forest shouldn't give you such results if you did set it up for classification.

However you can also set treshold with different values (0.5 ? 0.8 ?) depending on your need (You can use a ROC curve to help you determine the best classifier).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had set up a random forest for regression (imported the wrong class - silly me). Thanks for the links as well, I will try to implement cross-validations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for accurcay you should threshold at 0.5. I.e. any prediction that is >= 0.5 becomes 1, any prediction that is < 0.5 becomes 0. Of course you could pick any other threshold as well. E.g. with numpy this could be

```
class_predictions = np.where(prob_predictions >= 0.5, 1, 0)
```

This will return an array of integers 1 or 0.

Comment: Ok, I thought so, however, I was confused if this was a Big No No! What can be considered a good threshold? Isn't 0.5 too broad?

Comment: The general consensus is to simply pick the class with the highest probability. This is the "best" choice, so since you need to make a single choice eventually (if you want a single class label as output), might as well go with the "best" one. For two classes, the highest probability output is that which is > 0.5 (since the other one is then automatically < 0.5, so it's smaller).

Imagine extending this to more than two classes. If you have three classes with outputs [0.4, 0.3, 0.3], you're gonna pick the first one. It's close, but the first one is still your best bet.

Comment: As I said though (and as the other answer mentions), for two classes you could in principle pick any threshold you like (one that is not 0.5 might work better).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. This was extremely helpful.